# What textbook can I use to really understand microeconomics, macroeconomics and mathematical economics

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, reference-request, mathematical-economics

What textbook can I use to really understand microeconomics, macroeconomics and mathematical economics. It can be different textbooks. I'm in first year college taking introductory courses in microeconomics, macroeconomics and mathematical economics. I need a really good textbook or online site to understand what I'm studying well. I like the way people on this site answer and explain questions with application. I want to be like that too. I have Greg mankiw books by the way, I have schaum's introduction to mathematical economics. I need to read more quality books to understand.

Thanks

Comment: First year undergrad or first year grad student? If you're an undergrad, I'd start by double majoring in math. Get abstract linear algebra and real analysis under your belt. Then go from there.

Comment: First year undergrad. Alright thanks. Any recommendation for micro textbook or macro?

Comment: Hal Varian: Intermediate Microeconomics is a very good intro to micro. Later on (with more math under your belt) turn to Mas-Collel, Whinston, Green.

Comment: Quite ridiculous: When I was googling for the exact title of the Varian book half a year ago one of the top three hits was a full pdf of the book on a university website. And now googling the title gave me the full pdf from another university site. Seems like you can usually find it somewhere.

Comment: Varian is good. Double majoring in math is good. Osborne is good for game theory. Fudenberg and Tirole is more technical but also good for game theory. Fudenber and Tirole is more of a good grad level textbook though, though not as thick as MWG.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Economics.SE. We are very happy you're here and that you've liked the way the Q&A works on this website. This question is very broad and would thus make it difficult to answer which is why I'm voting to close. There are some questions related to book requests; try reading some of those questions (and answers) and possibly split this into multiple questions if there are remaining gaps in what topicsyou need references for.

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone... @denesp thanks. I just got the Hal Varian microeconomics. It's a really good intro to microeconomics. Please can suggest a good textbook for intro to macroeconomics?

Comment: @user274246 I really can't, so far I haven't read any that I liked. Follow cc7768's recommendation and browse other similar questions on this site. There are plenty.

Comment: @denesp alright thanks. Please do you have any links to any other related questions. I can't seem to find.

Comment: Did you try using the search bar? http://economics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breference-request%5D+macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For micro, I would recommend McCloskey's *Applied Theory of Price*, available to download from the author's website here: http://www.deirdremccloskey.com/docs/price.pdf

Read the opening section titled "how to use this book" to see why I think it matches well with your needs.

Another intermediate–advanced undergraduate level micro book in a similar vein to McCloskey is "Microeconomic Theory: Basic Principles and Extensions" by Walter Nicholson and Christopher Snyder.

For an enthusiastic undergraduate looking to read more mathematical economics, I would recommend "Fundamental Methods of Mathematical Economics" by Alpha Chiang. Some commenters are correct that graduate-level economics can take you into some fairly serious topics in analysis and other areas of pure mathematics. But for now I think you would be better served trying to get a solid handle on the core tool set used be economists. In my view, Chiang is a great place to learn those tools—being a bit more advanced than typical undergraduate material, but not completely abstracted.

Comment: Thanks. I've downloaded the book. It seems a little old but its quality

Comment: Can you please give me other book suggestions, sir?

Comment: @user274246 I added a couple of additional recommendations. I am afraid I don't know any good macro books.

Comment: Thanks sir. Checking them out now. The McCloskey book, was it written by Deirdre or Donald, sir?

Comment: @user274246 They are the same person.

Comment: Oh alright. Thanks for the help sir. I wish there was a way I could chat with you privately since you have so much knowledge in this field sir.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite broad, but here are a couple of (open) book sites you might get started with:
https://open.umn.edu/opentextbooks/SearchResults.aspx?subjectAreaId=4
http://www.freebookcentre.net/Business/Economics-Books.html

When you're familiar with the basics, you might ask the question again with a more specific topic you'd like to study.

Expertise on economics (or pretty much any academic subject) is gained through years of studying and thought. It's, at least to me, a fascinating way of thinking about the world.